# Basic Javascript If not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have made a basic javascript `if` statement but it does not seem to work. It doesn't replace the text in the Span 'box', but does without the if statement.

Here's my code:

```js
function show() {
  var span1 = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;

  if (span1 == 'asdf') {
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = 'test';
  }
}
```

```html
<span id = 'link'>
  <a onclick = 'show()' href = 'javascript:void(0);'>Show</a>
</span>
<span id = 'box'>
  asdf
</span>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, at first please define "not working".

Comment: @Teemu It doesn't replace the text in the Span 'box', but does without the if statement.

Comment: Can you output the span1 var? console.log('--'+span1+'--'); to see if it has spaces..

Comment: `console.log(span1)` and make sure there are no spaces around

Answer (score 4):

The string you're testing contains some whitespace (i.e. spaces, line breaks, tabulations) as well as the desired string.

You can remove the unnecessary whitespace characters when comparing:

```
 if (span1.replace(/\s/g, '') === 'asdf') {
```

Note: Of course be careful when using regular expressions. For instance, the above condition would also pass for strings like "   as df ". So you might want to improve upon that a bit.

Another solution would be to use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if (span1.indexOf('asdf') >= 0) {
```

You can also use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with an appropriate regular expression:

```
if (span1.match(/asdf/)) {
```

Edit: Also, if IE8 compatibility if not a concern for you, as suggested by @ungalcrys, you might consider using [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

---

**Side note**: consider using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`. See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) for some more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the innerHtml contains 2 new line characters at the begin and end of the `span1` variable

just after

```
var span1 = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
```

try and add:

```
alert('|' + span1 + '|');
```

and you will se exactly what I am refering about.

You could use `span1.trim()` to remove the whitespace before and after that string in JS.

Comment: I had mixed feelings - upvote or not. One the one hand, `trim()` is a good suggestion (and I'm ashamed to forget about that in my answer! I write too much IE8 compatible code :/), on the other hand using `alert()` for debugging isn't the greatest idea. Overall +1, though!

Comment: I agree, alert() is not a good ideea for debugging, I mostly use console.log(), but this is because I mainly develop for chrome and fix for other browsers later. 
So i had two reasons: Minifrij could be a begginer and he should understand this and this is ashort answer that will work on all browsers.

Anyway, thanks for the thumbs up.

Comment: Actually, basic support for console.log is there for basically every browser. And if anything, we should promote better practices. Anyway, alert is harder to miss than console.log, for beginners - that's for sure ;) Cheers!